# CFA Multitrait Multimethod in R?

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, structural-equation-modeling

Perhaps I am just searching the wrong way, but I am having a tough time trying to find out if there is already an R package that allows users to estimate multitrait multimethod structural equation models. Has anyone seen one?

EDIT: This is my model, where DEPFACT, ACAFACT, and SOCFACT are latent oblique trait factors and M_MET, F_MET, and K_MET are latent orthogonal method factors.

```
model <- specifyModel(text="
                      DEPFACT -> DEP_M,     a, 0.7
                      DEPFACT -> DEP_F,     b, 0.6
                      DEPFACT -> DEP_K,     c, 0.4
                      ACAFACT -> ACA_M,     d, 0.9
                      ACAFACT -> ACA_F,     e, 0.7
                      ACAFACT -> ACA_K,     f, 0.4
                      SOCFACT -> SOC_M,     g, 0.8
                      SOCFACT -> SOC_F,     h, 0.8
                      SOCFACT -> SOC_K,     i, 0.4
                      DEP_M <-> ACA_M,      j, -0.3
                      ACA_M <-> SOC_M,      k, 0.1
                      DEP_M <-> SOC_M,      l, 0.5
                      DEP_F <-> ACA_F,      m, -0.4
                      ACA_F <-> SOC_F,      n, 0.4
                      DEP_F <-> SOC_F,      o, 0.2
                      DEP_K <-> ACA_K,      p, -0.7
                      ACA_K <-> SOC_K,      q, 0.6
                      DEP_K <-> SOC_K,      r, 0.6
                      DEPFACT <-> ACAFACT,  s, -0.5
                      ACAFACT <-> SOCFACT,  t, 0.3
                      DEPFACT <-> SOCFACT,  u, -0.7
                      DEPFACT <-> DEPFACT,  NA, 1
                      ACAFACT <-> ACAFACT,  NA, 1
                      SOCFACT <-> SOCFACT,  NA, 1
                      ")
```

Which produces the model...

```
Path                Parameter StartValue
1  DEPFACT -> DEP_M    a         0.7       
2  DEPFACT -> DEP_F    b         0.6       
3  DEPFACT -> DEP_K    c         0.4       
4  ACAFACT -> ACA_M    d         0.9       
5  ACAFACT -> ACA_F    e         0.7       
6  ACAFACT -> ACA_K    f         0.4       
7  SOCFACT -> SOC_M    g         0.8       
8  SOCFACT -> SOC_F    h         0.8       
9  SOCFACT -> SOC_K    i         0.4       
10 M_MET -> DEP_M      j         -0.3      
11 M_MET -> ACA_M      k         0.1       
12 M_MET -> SOC_M      l         0.5       
13 F_MET -> DEP_F      m         -0.4      
14 F_MET -> ACA_F      n         0.4       
15 F_MET -> SOC_F      o         0.2       
16 K_MET -> DEP_K      p         -0.7      
17 K_MET -> ACA_K      q         0.6       
18 K_MET -> SOC_K      r         0.6       
19 DEPFACT <-> ACAFACT s         -0.5      
20 ACAFACT <-> SOCFACT t         0.3       
21 DEPFACT <-> SOCFACT u         -0.7      
22 DEPFACT <-> DEPFACT <fixed>   1         
23 ACAFACT <-> ACAFACT <fixed>   1         
24 SOCFACT <-> SOCFACT <fixed>   1         
25 M_MET <-> M_MET     <fixed>   1         
26 F_MET <-> F_MET     <fixed>   1         
27 K_MET <-> K_MET     <fixed>   1         
28 DEP_M <-> DEP_M     V[DEP_M]            
29 DEP_F <-> DEP_F     V[DEP_F]            
30 DEP_K <-> DEP_K     V[DEP_K]            
31 ACA_M <-> ACA_M     V[ACA_M]            
32 ACA_F <-> ACA_F     V[ACA_F]            
33 ACA_K <-> ACA_K     V[ACA_K]            
34 SOC_M <-> SOC_M     V[SOC_M]            
35 SOC_F <-> SOC_F     V[SOC_F]            
36 SOC_K <-> SOC_K     V[SOC_K]
```

Comment: lavaan, sem, openMX. An MTMM is a CFA, so any package that does CFA.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I tried it with the sem package cfa and couldn't get it to converge, as compared to the same analysis conducted in LISREL. Fooled around with the convergence criteria and iterations but still couldn't get it to work. I'll try it out with lavaan next.

Comment: Are you sure the models matched? Did your df match? You could try putting the LISREL results in as starting values in the sem model.

Comment: Pretty sure. And yeah, I tried that with the starting values. I keep getting the "Could not compute QR decomposition of Hessian" error. I've checked my model over multiple times (I've added it to my question) and I don't see any problems with it that should cause this problem.

Comment: Can you put the code that you specify the model with?

Comment: You are fixing values for every loading (I think). You should fix one of them to 1.00, and let the rest be free.

Comment: From what I understand, I'm actually estimating all of the loadings and specifying start values. And then I fix the factor variances to 1. Does that match what I have up there?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use the sem package. I would  try a simple model and see if that works.

Comment: Which do you use? Any you might suggest? I've seen lavaan and openMX but haven't explored all of the differences.

Comment: I use lavaan. It's not dissimilar to sem, but has a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, but I should note that I tried it out in lavaan and it worked fine.